# How do I see the actual Map Reduce job in Hadoop from beyond all abstractions?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a Hadoop Cluster.  On top of that is HBase.  On top of that is Phoenix.  When I execute `SELECT * FROM TEST LIMIT 1000;` from Phoenix... how do I actually see what job was sent to hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix does this using parallel scans using Hbase coporcessors and not using map reduce jobs. You can see the details of the query plan by doing

> explain SELECT * FROM TEST LIMIT 1000;

If you need more details, route the logs from phoenix to a different log category on hbase server.